# An explanation of web sockets and server-side Javascript (especially focused on node.js)

Tags: javascript, sockets, server-side, node.js

I want to create a chat room using HTML5 web sockets, but am pretty lost. From what I can tell, the following is required:

1. A browser that supports web sockets (Chrome, Safari)
2. Some kind of server-side scripting
3. Some kind of client-side scripting

I've got #1 down :) but #2 is seriously tripping me up. Beyond amateur PHP work (generally within the context of Drupal), I have pretty much no experience coding on the server-side of things. I tend to code a lot in Javascript, and have read fantastic things about node.js. So I thought I'd try using it to play around with web sockets.

I've installed node.js to my Mac Leopard machine (it installs to Home > node), but I really have no idea where to go from there. The node.js website provides a "Hello World" example, which I've tried (I put the code into an example.js file, and saved that in the root of the "node" folder), but I only get the following response in Terminal:

> *Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/*

I would LOVE a node.js and web sockets for dummies kind of thing. Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: Check out Jeff Kreeftmeijer's "ghost pointers" experiment. That's effectively the framework you need for realtime chat; you just interpret the data differently clientside. http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/experimenting-with-node-js/

Comment: The "hello world" is the response if you make a web request to http://127.0.0.1:8124

Comment: mhitza--

okay. how do i make that request?

Comment: start the server and then enter the above 127.0.0.1:8124 URL in your browser.

before diving into node.js and websockets, it might be good to get a better understanding of http protocol internals and the asynchronous event model, since they rely heavily on this.

Comment: Thanks shreddd. Can you recommend any resources on those two subjects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be slightly more advanced but it does provide a decent WebSocket layer for node.js: http://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node

That said, if you haven't done much server-side stuff, it might be better to get a feeling for the http protocol including how a request and response is constructed, how headers are added etc. (outside of node). Once you have a better sense for this, node.js will be much easier to understand.

This tutorial should give you a basic overview:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/index.htm

This stuff becomes even more important when dealing with websockets

Answer (score 2):

This is also easy in RingoJs http://ringojs.org if you want to stick with JavaScript on the serverside. This is the gist of what you write to have a websocket Listener.

```
  var websocket = require("ringo/webapp/websocket");

  exports.serverStarted = function(server) {
      var context = server.getDefaultContext();
      websocket.addWebSocket(context, "/websocket", function (socket) {
          // this function, being passed the socket, is called everytime
          // a new socket connection is made.

          // overwrite onMessage to intercept the messages         
          socket.onmessage = function(m) {
          };
      });
  };

  // send smth to the client
 fooSocket.send('your message')
```

Inside socket.onmessage you just grab the message and work with it. You will probably store the sockets somewhere to have access to them later on.

See:

- http://gist.github.com/555596 (the example above but more elaborate)
- http://ringojs.org/api/master/ringo/webapp/websocket/ Websocket Ringo API

Answer (score 1):

There is a demo project on the node.js site with a live chat.
http://chat.nodejs.org/

and the source code is here.
http://github.com/ry/node_chat

this is not using html5 but hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I've seen that, but I don't know what to do with it. As I said in the original post, I don't even understand the Hello World example.